# Does bitcoin 0.16.1 work with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Windows 10?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, windows, installation

Does the bitcoin core for ubuntu work with windows 10 WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) command line? What issues are there if any since its install the ubuntu version under windows 10.

Comment: What do you mean by Bitcoin Core for Ubuntu? The release Linux binaries are statically linked and should work on every distro. If you're talking about the PPA, perhaps not so much.

Answer (score 1):

it should work, but filesystem access from within WSL might be slower then using the windows server. There are some benchmarks available. Perhaps another alternative to consider would be running Bitcoin Core in vagrant. I don't know if and how bitcoind would be slower.

Comment: Looking for anyone that has actually got it installed and tested.